# Json_agg slow down the performance

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a database, simulate a structure of a document, like this

table `document`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Id | 
-------------------------------------------------
|  1    |
```

table `section`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Id | document_id |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1    | 1 |
```

table `article`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Id | section_id |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1    | 1 |
```

table `paragraph`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Id | article_id |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1    | 1 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  2    | 1 |
```

table `paragraph_text`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Id | para_id | content | locale |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1    | 1 | text1 in englisht | en |
--------------------------------------------------
|  2    | 1 | text1 in french | fr |
--------------------------------------------------
|  3    | 2 | text2 in english | en |
--------------------------------------------------
|  4    | 2 | text2 in french | fr |
```

Firsly, I want to have this result:

```
[
  {
    "articles": [
      {
        "elements": [
          {
            "translations": {
              "en": {
                "content": text1 in eng"
              },
              "fr": {
                "content": "text1 in fr"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "translations": {
              "en": {
                "content": "text2 in en"
              },
              "fr": {
                "content": "text2 in fr"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So that, i have launched this query, which is performs perfectly fine

```
select
    --- section
        (select json_agg(section_agg)
        from (
            select
                --- articles
                (select json_agg(articles_agg) 
                from (
                    select
                        --- elements
                        (select json_agg(elements_agg) 
                        from (
                            select
                                --- translations
                                (select jsonb_object_agg(locale, json_build_object( 'content', content))
                                from (
                                    select locale,  content
                                    from test.paragraph_text et
                                    where et.para_id = e.id 
                                ) element_translation_agg) as translations
                            from test.paragraph e
                            where e.article_id = a.id
                        ) elements_agg ) as elements
                    from test.article a
                    where a.section_id = l.id
                ) articles_agg) as articles
            from test.section l
            where l.document_id = w.id
        ) section_agg) as section
from test.document w
order by w.id
```

But after that, i want to merge the content of the paragraph in same article together, that is when the performance goes very slow
To do merge, i created a table like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.element_boost;
create table test.element_boost as 

    with json_locale as (   
        with merged_element as (
            SELECT  a.id as article_id, aet.locale as locale, string_agg(trim(coalesce(aet.content, '')), ' ') as content
            FROM test.article a
            join test.paragraph ae on ae.article_id = a.id 
            join test.paragraph_text aet on aet.para_id = ae.id
            group by a.id, aet.locale
        )
        select  me.article_id as article_id, json_object_agg(me.locale, me.content) as content
        from merged_element me
        where me.content is not null or trim(me.content) <> ''
        group by me.article_id
        order by me.article_id
    )
    select  dl.document_id as document_id, dl.id as level_id, da.id as article_id,  
            jl.content
    from test.section dl
    left join test.article da on da.section_id = dl.id
    left join json_locale jl on jl.article_id = da.id
```

and then i rewrite the query above by using table `element_boost`

```
select
    (select json_agg(levels_agg)
    from (
        select
            a.level_id as level_id, a.article_id as article_id,
            a.content
        from test.element_boost a
        where a.document_id = d.id
        order by a.level_id, a.article_id
    ) levels_agg) as nested_articles
from test.document d
order by d.id
```

But at this point, the query goes extremly slow, i have test on 100 documents, the first query took 3s to finish, but the second one took 5 times, about 15s to finish. I don't really understand why cz the 2 query are quite the same. The only difference is that column `content` of `element_boost` is big because it is the merged column of all elements in the same article.
Thank a lot for your help.